# Scrape a list of websites simultaneously using Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape multiple product catalogues and each link is the link towards a different product.

Webpages is a data frame containing the links.

```
webpages
"https............"
"https............"
"https............"
```

I have the following code:

```
for (i in webpages){
    book_page <- read_html(link) 
}
```

I got this error `Error: x must be a string of length 1`,

may I know how could I resolve it?

Comment: You need to mention column name `webpages$colname`

Answer (score 1):

A for loop does not download multiple website at the same time as required by the title of your question. However, you can use a parallelization package e.g. [pbmcapply](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbmcapply/index.html):

```r
library(rvest)
library(readr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'readr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:rvest':
#> 
#>     guess_encoding
library(pbmcapply)
#> Loading required package: parallel

webpages <- list(
  "http://example.com",
  "https://stackoverflow.com/",
  "https://github.com/"
)

# download 3 webpages at the same time
contents <- pbmclapply(webpages, read_file, mc.cores = 3)
contents_html <- lapply(contents, read_html)
contents_html[[1]]
#> {html_document}
#> <html>
#> [1] <head>\n<title>Example Domain</title>\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n<meta http ...
#> [2] <body>\n<div>\n    <h1>Example Domain</h1>\n    <p>This domain is for use ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

`read_html` must be executed in the main thread to circumvent pointer errors.

Comment: thank you danloo. I have tried your solution it works but "ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in doc_type(x): external pointer is not valid" is returned

Comment: @Coderz I revised my answer